# How to convert word document text into HTML in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, admin

I will enter the text into the input box and the output I should get is properly converted HTML with all paragraph tags, ul tags, ol tags, header, etc

Comment: For this purpose you can use "ckeditor" or any other html text editor which you like. search about it.

Comment: You can just use a service like https://wordhtml.com/ and copy the converted html text into your Laravel template page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use any rich text editor achieve this, like

ckerditor : https://ckeditor.com/

tynimce :https://www.tiny.cloud/

wysiwyg : https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/

read documentation before using it